# Conditional in fluent interface in Azure java SDK

Tags: java, spring, azure, spring-boot, azure-java-sdk

I am creating a linux vm using a custom image from an shared image gallery using java sdk.

```
virtualMachine = azure.virtualMachines()
                        .define(linuxVMName)
                        .withRegion(location)
                        .withExistingResourceGroup(resourceGroup)
                        .withExistingPrimaryNetworkInterface(networkInterface)
                        .withLinuxCustomImage(customImageUrl)
                        .withRootUsername(username)
                        .withRootPassword(password)
                        .withCustomData(custDatastring)
                        .withComputerName(linuxVMName)
                        .withExistingStorageAccount(storageAccount)
                        .withSize(vmSize())
                        .create();
```

this also supports creating linux instances from generic public images also like

```
.withLatestLinuxImage(publisher, offer, sku)
```

What I want to know is
whether it is possible to use conditional statements in this pattern like whether Azure has implemented that part.

Another scenario is instead of root password, i can also use root SSH, so many conditions here

I had no luck with the documentation part also.
Yes I can write an whole if else and copy paste the code also, I just want to know is there a better way to implement this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to create vm with ssh key, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/virtualmachines?view=azure-java-stable#example

Comment: Hi @JimXu, my question is how to handle conditional part in fluent interface

Comment: Hi. We have no way to do that with Azure sdk. We need to implement it by ourselves.

Comment: Thats bad, Thanks

Comment: Do you have any other concerns?

Comment: I have one completely unrelated to this, can i ask here or create a new question for that. Its regarding azure subscription's quotas and limits

Comment: If you have a new issue, I suggest you create a new .

Comment: okay Thanks, will do